# Почему при запуске программы и вводе любого другого литерала кроме 'S' цикл повторяется 3 раза а не 1?

Tags: java

```
class Prog14 {
    public static void main (String args []) throws java.io.IOException {
         int i;
         System.out.println ("Dlja ostanovki cikla najmite S");

         for (i=0; (char)System.in.read()!='S'; i++)
                 System.out.println ("Popitka "+i);

    }
}
```

Comment: Расскажи, что ты ожидаешь от этого кода

Comment: Это один из демонстративных кодов из книги Шилдта, в нем он показывает что можно создать цикл For который будет выполняться пока не введен литерал 'S'. Я не могу понять, почему при вводе любого другого литерала цикл выполняется именно 3 раза а не 1, т.к. в итерации только i++ а других условий, кроме ввода 'S' не задано.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вот.
P.s. не самый красивый код, который я писал, но тем не менее

```
class Prog14 {
public static void main (String args []) throws java.io.IOException {
    int i=0;

    System.out.println ("Dlja ostanovki cikla najmite S");
    
    while ((char)System.in.read()!='S'){
        i++;
        System.out.println ("Popitka "+i);
        System.in.read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Тут не было никакой задачи, тут был вопрос, почему код ведет себя определенным образом.

Comment: ДА. именно так. Объясни пожалуйста. Я что то совсем понять понять не могу

Comment: @Денис, здесь дело в System.in.read, он производит считывание ровно одного байта (символа в нашем случае), а мы вводим несколько (сам символ и /n, где /n - это перенос строк. обеспечиваемый клавишей Enter). И таким образом команде System.in есть что считывать из строки "A/n" ещё несколько итераций.

Comment: Теперь разобрался, спасибо! Цикл повторяется 3 раза потому что для считывания данных с консоли, методу System.in.read() нужно 3 итерации по 1 байту. В первой он считывает сам символ, во второй \n - перенос строки, и в третьей он считывает \r - возврат каретки